# "KeyError": (column title) while batch downloading dataset and dropping rows?

Tags: python, pandas

```
trainchunks = pd.read_csv('emnist-byclass-train.csv', header=0, delimiter=",", engine='c', na_filter=False, dtype=np.int64, chunksize=50000)
for chk in trainchunks:
  chk.columns.values[0]="labels"
  print(chk.columns)
  for i in range(9,63):
    chk=chk[chk["labels"]!=i]

  Y_trainchunk = chk['labels']
  # Normalize the data
  chk = chk / 255.0

  # Reshape image in 3 dimensions (height = 282px, width = 28px , canal = 1)
  chk = chk.values.reshape(-1,28,28,1)

  # Encode labels to one hot vectors (ex : 2 -> [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
  Y_trainchunk = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes = 26)
```

I'm trying to process the data in batches because I run into memory errors when I process the EMNIST dataset as a whole. I only want the lowercase letters a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h (first 8 classes I believe?) so I want to get rid of everything after that. This is the problem I'm getting, and it happens even if I don't load in batches: this is the result from that run—

```
     labels  0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  ...    0.466  \
0           36  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
1            6  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
2            3  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
3           22  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
4           38  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
5            5  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
6            9  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
7           47  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
8            4  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
9            7  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
10          56  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
11          29  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
12          40  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
13          55  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
14           6  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
15          55  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
16          57  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
17          43  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
18           6  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
19           3  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
20           7  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
21          32  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
22           3  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
23          40  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
24           9  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
25          22  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
26          15  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
27          26  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
28           2  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
29           5  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
...        ... ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...      ...   
697901      55  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697902      49  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697903      24  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697904       3  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697905       1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697906       5  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697907       6  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697908      40  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697909      24  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697910       9  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697911       8  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697912      43  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697913       4  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697914       9  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697915      43  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697916       7  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697917       2  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697918      32  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697919      40  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697920      53  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697921       8  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697922       5  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697923      47  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697924       1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697925      23  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697926      40  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697927      47  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697928       5  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697929      11  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   
697930      22  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...        0   

        0.467  0.468  0.469  0.470  0.471  0.472  0.473  0.474  0.475  
0           0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
1           0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
2           0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
3           0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
4           0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
5           0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
6           0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
7           0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
8           0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
9           0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
10          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
11          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
12          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
13          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
14          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
15          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
16          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
17          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
18          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
19          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
20          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
21          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
22          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
23          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
24          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
25          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
26          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
27          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
28          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
29          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
...       ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...  
697901      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697902      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697903      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697904      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697905      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697906      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697907      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697908      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697909      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697910      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697911      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697912      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697913      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697914      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697915      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697916      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697917      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697918      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697919      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697920      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697921      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697922      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697923      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697924      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697925      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697926      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697927      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697928      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697929      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
697930      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  

[697931 rows x 785 columns]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2524             try:
-> 2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'labels'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8934d31c2365> in <module>()
      4 print(train)
      5 for i in range(27,63):
----> 6    train=train[train["labels"]!=i]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2137             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2138         else:
-> 2139             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2140 
   2141     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2144         # get column
   2145         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2146             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2147 
   2148         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1840         res = cache.get(item)
   1841         if res is None:
-> 1842             values = self._data.get(item)
   1843             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1844             cache[item] = res

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3841 
   3842             if not isna(item):
-> 3843                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3844             else:
   3845                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:
-> 2527                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2528 
   2529         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'labels'
```

It's formatted oddly on here, but the "labels" title is directly above the first column in my console. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to pandas myself, but if you ask for a label that does not exist you get a KeyError.

This code shows that a column named 'labelz' works and a column named 'labels' gives a KeyError. If you still see a KeyError after renaming the column, it must be related to something else.

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Col1':'labelz'}) # the word "labels" is reserved and will give KeyError
df3 = df2.rename(columns={'labelz':'labels'}) # the word "labels" is reserved and will give KeyError

print("df2")
print(df2)
for i in range(5,7):
    df2=df2[df2["labelz"] != i]
print("df2")
print(df2)
#
print("df3")
print(df3)
for i in range(5,7):
    df3=df3[df2["labels"] != i]
print("df3")
print(df3)

Output:
df2
      labelz  Col2  Col3
Row4       4     6     1
Row5       5     1     1
Row6       6     2     0
Row7       7     4    -1
Row8       8     6    -2
df2
      labelz  Col2  Col3
Row4       4     6     1
Row7       7     4    -1
Row8       8     6    -2
df3
      labels  Col2  Col3
Row4       4     6     1
Row5       5     1     1
Row6       6     2     0
Row7       7     4    -1
Row8       8     6    -2
KeyError: 'labels'
```

Comment: But I set the label myself in the code above? It must be there, right?

Comment: I do not understand some of what your code is doing, could you explain these lines?
 for i in range(9,63):
    chk=chk[chk["labels"]!=i]

Comment: I'm trying to loop through all data classes labelled from 9 to 63 and eliminate rows that have those values for the column titled "labels"

Comment: I see 9 in the list, are you sure 63 is in the list?

Comment: I think the problem is your for loop.  It is looping from 9 to 62 and for every iteration it creates another chk. You want just one with labels 9 to 62 taken out.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but this might work:
chk.loc[lambda df: df.labels < 9 or df.labels > 62, : ]

Comment: I tested this and it worked:
chk = chk.loc[chk.labuls < 10, :]
chk = chk.loc[chk.labuls > 62, :]
I had to rename labels to labuls. That makes me wonder if "labels" is reserved.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8082
This link talks about reserved words including:
index,major_axis,minor_axis,items,labels

Comment: So, the problem was not your for loop, just the fact that you used the word "labels" to name a column.

Comment: Oh boy, I thought of that before. I had "label" originally, so I changed it to "labels" thinking I could ignore that possible issue. Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind answering with the working code? I tried it with 'labelz' and same error